# Firebase Database - Retrieve Multiple Entries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data is denormalized and uses a reverse index like suggested by the firebase team. Something similar to:

```
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Now I want to load all of Ada's groups. I can easily get a list of the group IDs that she belongs to since it's part of her user object.

Is there a way for me to query all of Ada's specific groups by ID at once? Or do I need to create a `ValueEventListener` per group ID and request each group separately?

On the security side - let's assume that every group is only readable by its members, so I can't query all groups and sort them after the fact.

Comment: Most applications through the keys from the index and load each group individually. That's not a big performance drain, since Firebase pipelines the database requests. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you mean that if I loop through the list and set a `ValueEventListener` for each of them, the DB will optimize the way it retrieves the data on its own? Or do I have to request the data in a certain way?

Comment: All requests go through the same connection. The only difference between `get(1)`, `get(2)`, `get(3)` and `getAll([1,2,3])` is some overhead for the frames.

Comment: @ItaiHanski also struggling with the same issue - did you find a better solution? All answers I've found seen like a "hack".

Comment: @eth0 Not really. I basically create a listener per group and wait until all of them return an answer to logically be "loaded"

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like:

```
var ref = new Firebase("<..>/groups");
ref.orderByChild("members/alovelace").equalTo(true)
  .once('value').then(function(dataSnapshot) {
     // handle read data
})
```

(Untested, but according to [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) Deep-Queries are now supported)

Comment: in Android use this: Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("groups").orderByChild("members/" + user.getId()).equalTo(true); . this is one query for all data!

Comment: This approach has 2 drawbacks IMO: First, from a security standpoint - this means that every user can read the entire `groups` tree, and second, If I have a huge number of groups this would probably be a little slow and wasteful. I already know the exact IDs of the groups I'm interested in - seems a shame not to use it.

Comment: @ItaiHanski did you figure out the solution?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Nothing fancy. Iterate through all of the fetches and make sure they all return.